# can any one provide complete script to compare csv file and SharePoint list column(People) and extract records not exist in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, csom, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

I have one excel file and a SharePoint list(Employee master). I want to extract the user in csv file who is not in the SharePoint list(Employee Master).

If the employee not exists in SharePoint list we treat him as user terminated for internal tracking.

Please provide the PowerShell solution or if any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script which work in my end. I used title column in csv file just for testing. You can replace the placeholder with the column name in your list. I only test with single text column. If you are using people and group column for user name. It may needs a bit more work and just let me know.

```
$ListName="<ListName>"
$csv=Import-Csv "<CSV file Path>"
$webURL="<Site URL>"
$web=Get-SPWeb $webURl
$list=$web.Lists | Where-Object { $_.Title -Eq $ListName }
$TerminatedUserList=@()
foreach ($row in $csv) 
{ 
    $Items= $list.items | where {$_['<column Name>'] -eq $row.Title}
    If($Items.Length -eq 0)
    {
        write-host $row.Title "does not exist in the SP list"
        $TerminatedUserList+=$row.Title
    }

}
```